# how to extract word from grep result in shell?

Tags: shell

Using shell i want to search and print only sub-string with next word to that sub-string.

e.g. logfile has line "today is monday and this is:1234 so I am in."

```
if grep -q "this is :" ./logfile; then
   #here i want to print only sub-string with next word i.e. "this is:1234"
   #echo ???
fi
```

Comment: How long of a file? If it's short, it can be faster to do that search in native shell rather than spawning external tools (`grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc), though those tools will generally process content faster once the cost to start them up is paid.

Comment: BTW, the outer `if grep -q` is arguably a bad idea -- means you're reading the file twice, once to check its contents, and then again to read its contents. If you're going to run an external command, better to use `if result=$(that-command); then ...` to both capture output and check exit status in one pass. If the command isn't setting exit status based on whether there's a match, then `if result=$(that-command) && [ -n "$result" ]; then` may make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with `\1` to display the matched string in `\(..\)`:

```
sed 's/.*\(this is:[0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' logfile
```

EDIT: The above command is only fine for 1 line input.

When you have a file with more lines, you only want to print the lines that match:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(this is:[0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/p' logfile
```

When you have a large file and only want to see the first match, you can combine this command with `head -1`, but you would like to stop scanning/parsing after the first match. You can use `q` to quit, but you only want to quit after a match.

```
sed -n '/.*\(this is:[0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/{s//\1/p;q}'
```

Comment: If you amended this to also eliminate every other line, and exit after finding a match, I'd think we'd be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with a [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), if you want only the next word:

```
$ grep --perl-regexp -o '(?<=(this is:))(\S+)' ./logfile
1234
```

If you want both, then just:

```
$ grep --perl-regexp -o 'this is:\S+' ./logfile
this is:1234
```

The `-o` option instructs `grep` to return only the matching part.

In the commands above, we assumed that a "word" is a sequence of non-space characters. You can adjust that according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for everything up to, but not including the next space like this:

```
grep -Eo "this is:[^[:space:]]+" logfile
```

The `[]` introduces the set of characters you are looking for and the `^` at the start complements the set, so the set of characters you are looking for is a blank space, but complemented, i.e. not a blank space. The `+` says there must be at least one or more such characters.

The `-E` tells `grep` to use extended regular expressions and the `-o` means to only print the matched part.

Comment: I'd suggest using `[^[:space:]]` to also stop at tab characters &c.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, that is a definite improvement - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system with GNU extensions (but aren't certain it was compiled with optional PCRE support), consider:

```
if result=$(grep -E -m 1 -o 'this is:[^[:space:]]+' logfile); then
  echo "value is: ${result#*:}"
fi
```

`${varname#value}` expands to the contents of `varname`, but with `value` stripped from the beginning if present. Thus, `${result#*:}` strips everything up to the first colon in `result`.

However, this may not work on systems without the non-POSIX options `-o` or `-m`.

---

If you want to support non-GNU systems, `awk` is a tool worth considering: Unlike answers requiring nonportable extensions (like `grep -P`), this should work on any modern platform (tested with GNU awk, recent BSD awk, and mawk; also, no warnings with with `gawk --posix --lint`):

```
# note that the constant 8 is the length of "this is:"
# GNU awk has cleaner syntax, but trying to be portable here.
if value=$(awk '
  BEGIN { matched=0; }      # by default, this will trigger END to exit as failure
  /this is:/ {
    match($0, /this\ is:([^[:space:]]+)/);
    print substr($0, RSTART+8, RLENGTH-8);
    matched=1;              # tell END block to use zero exit status
    exit(0);                # stop processing remaining file contents, jump to END
  }
  END { if(matched == 0) { exit(1); } }
'); then
  echo "Found value of $value"
else
  echo "Could not find $value in file"
fi
```